# How to query which RuboCop rules apply to a file?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am working on a tool to analyze how rubocop is used (enabled/disabled) and fixed (excluded into todo lists) in certain areas of the codebase. Given the multitude of config options, I *think* I am looking for a way to programmatically ask RuboCop whether given a file or folder, a certain rule is enabled and whether this file is excluded via a todo or not. Is there an API for this?

I have so far spelunked in https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop to see if I could find an API... Searched via SO and google and can't find anything.

Comment: If you take a look at how the `--list-target-files` and `--show-cops` flags are implemented, it might give some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's public interface for what you want.  [This `mobilize_team` method in the Runner](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/v1.56.4/lib/rubocop/runner.rb#L364) is what instantiates a `RuboCop::Cop::Team`. The team object determines the cops to use in [this `roundup_relevant_cops` method](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/v1.56.4/lib/rubocop/cop/team.rb#L160).  Both of these methods are private, but you could use `send` to work around that.

For example, say that we have a project with two files called `test_one.rb` and `test_two.rb`.

The `.rubocop_todo.yml` says that one of the files still needs to be handled:

```yaml
# .rubocop_todo.yml
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Exclude:
    - 'test_two.rb'
```

The `.rubocop.yml` config says that we just care about `Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment`:

```yaml
# .rubocop.yml
inherit_from: .rubocop_todo.yml

AllCops:
  DisabledByDefault: true

Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: true
```

We can see the cops that RuboCop will apply to each file if we do this:

```rb
require 'rubocop'

# Set up the Runner. Assumes no special command line options are involved.
options, _paths = RuboCop::Options.new.parse([])
config_store = RuboCop::ConfigStore.new
runner = RuboCop::Runner.new(options, config_store)

# For each file, figure out which cops are enabled for that file
['test_one.rb', 'test_two.rb'].each do |filename|
  full_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, filename)
  config = config_store.for_file(full_path)
  source = RuboCop::ProcessedSource.from_file(full_path, config.target_ruby_version)
  team = runner.send(:mobilize_team, source)
  cops = team.send(:roundup_relevant_cops, source)
  puts "#{filename}: #{cops.map(&:name).join(', ')}"
end
```

This will show this output:

```
test_one.rb: Lint/Syntax, Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment
test_two.rb: Lint/Syntax
```

Because of [this special condition in `enable_cop?`](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/v1.56.4/lib/rubocop/config.rb#L312) the `Lint/Syntax` cop is always enabled. And since `test_one.rb` isn't included in the TODO list, it is the only file that qualifies for the `Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment` cop.

Comment: Amazing writeup! Thank you so much